# Calculating SQL join transfer cost

Tags: mysql, join, cloud

I have this SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EMP (
EID varchar(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ENAME VARCHAR(40),
ESALARY DOUBLE,
DID VARCHAR(4));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEP (
DID varchar(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
DNAME VARCHAR(16),
DLOCATION VARCHAR(30));

SELECT * FROM EMP -> executed in T3 location
JOIN DID ON EMP.DID = DEP.DID;
```

`EMP` is on node T1 and DEP is on node T2.

If transfer `cost = size data` then how can I calculate the execution cost:

1. if T1 and T2 are transferred in T3 and then EMP JOIN DEP is
   happen?
2. if DEP is transferred to T1 -> EMP JOIN DEP result
   transferred T3?
3. if EMP is transferred to T2 -> EMP JOIN DEP
   result transferred to T3?